# Rails Routes :requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want to set a route :requirements on an array that verifies a particular parameter is included in an array:

```
atypes = [:culture, :personality, :communication]  
map.with_options(:path_prefix => ':atype',  
  :requirements => {:atype => atypes.include?(:atype)}) do |assessment|  
  ...
end
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to accomplish this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`:requirements` option expects regular expression. Something like `/(culture|presonality|communication)/`. You can also construct one from the array:

```
atypes = [:culture, :personality, :communication]  
map.with_options(:path_prefix => ':atype',  
  :requirements => /(#{atypes.join('|')})/ ) do |assessment|  
  ...
end
```